# Terraform with Azure - Issue enforcing unique names for resources

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am using Terraform for creating resources within Azure and attaching current time-stamp for enforcing unique names for resources like storage account, key vault etc in the .tf file.

Problem is, for existing resources, when you expect Terraform apply to do nothing, these resources are being destroyed and recreated since the time-stamp has changed between last execution and the current one!

Wondering what's the best strategy to enforce uniqueness, dynamically.

The initial texts for these resources come from Azure Pipeline variables and I'm appending current time-stamp for adding uniqueness.

Comment: Please add the config to the question so that we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

According to Cloud Adoption framework you could define a convention like the one shown below.

[image]

Terraform example

```
name = "${local.prefix}-${var.location}-app-plan"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-naming

I also suggest you to look the naming azure plugin which can help you create unique names across resources

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/naming/azurerm/latest